# Show 1 month job on resume?

Tags: resume, job-change, termination

I recently got fired from a company after working there for 6 weeks.

This was my 3rd place of employment, having previously been employed for 8 and 3 years respectively.

I would like to avoid listing this experience on my resume/LinkedIn, however I am in the United States on an H1B Work Visa, and may need to disclose all previous employment when applying for a new one (through my employers)

My intention is to disclose it to a potential employer after getting deep in the interview process but before accepting any offer.

Is this the best way to handle it?

Comment: i'm not sure why you think you need to disclose this at all to anyone? if it isn't on your CV and you don't tell a bg check company about it, how and why would anyone know? and you typically don't get in trouble for not mentioning things you did (unless it was, you know, jail-worthy)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere This is software development job and I was told that I am slow as compared to the team which is true to an extent. I was however getting up to speed and would have been productive in maybe another month. The other reason could be due to my conduct. I joined as a senior developer and started questioning technical decisions and development practices almost immediately in meetings after joining. I think this rubbed the VP of engineering in wrong way.

Comment: Check some of the related questions such as http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50015/should-i-list-an-employer-that-fired-me-after-two-weeks or http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32432/should-i-tell-new-employer-i-omitted-a-job-on-cv

Answer (score 2):

My question is: did it in any way impact the job you would be doing, whether that be gaining experience or exercising duties that would be relevant to the new job. If so, include it. You can explain the situation surrounding it at that point, IF they ask. Or you can volunteer the circumstances.

However, I sincerely think that (in effect) hiding it until late in the process will reflect poorly on you, as they would wonder why it wasn't disclosed in the first place. Did you do something wrong? Were you hiding some sort of misconduct?

I've had 30-day periods where they were reviewing my performance and then let me go. NOT for performance issues, but because they couldn't afford me, they hired someone else or they decided they hadn't the need for me anymore.

The previous two jobs having a LONG period of employment will offset the month job, and missing periods of time lead to more questions than are worth having to explain away.

Comment: I didn't do anything particularly interesting during that 1 month to put on my resume. I've had far better achievements in my earlier companies. Thanks for your opinion about disclosing it late.

Comment: Interesting doesn't equate to useful, though. If what you did was in line with your new job (ie you made a website and are applying as a developer of any type) as opposed to...well...not (you were flipping burgers or working as a cashier). A good way to think of it is this: A company doesn't care that you worked at McDonalds in High School because it doesn't relate to your new aspiration as a juggler, so you can safely leave it off. If you're applying to be a cashier at Wal-Mart it might pertain as you're working in customer service.